# Can I use skills with a sword of light in SAGA Marvel system?

Tags: marvel-saga

In SAGA Marvel system, one can use the light sword stunt from the power Light Control to create a sword.

Can I associete the skill Sword when using this power with this stunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Several example characters in the books have this combination -  just remember that in doing so, you change the suit of the trump to strength from whatever it is for light control (intellect, I think?)